# Inner product identity not understood

Tags: inner-products

Reading Axler Linear Algebra Done Right, [page 205](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-031-41026-0.pdf#page=223), about determining the representing vector in Riesz representation of a linear functional, We're given this (rephrased):

- $V$ is an inner product space with an orthonormal basis $e_1, \dotsb, e_m$
- $\varphi$ is a linear functional of $V$, $v \in V$

$$
\begin {align}
\varphi(v)
&= \left\langle v, e_{1} \right\rangle \varphi(e_{1})
 + \dotsb
 + \left\langle v, e_{m} \right\rangle \varphi(e_{m})
\\
&= \left\langle 
   v,
   \overline {\varphi(e_{1})} e_{1} 
   + \dotsb
   + \overline {\varphi(e_{m})} e_{m}
   \right\rangle 
\end {align}
$$

and with that $\varphi(v) = \left \langle v, u \right \rangle$ with $u = \overline {\varphi(e_{1})} e_{1} + \dotsb + \overline {\varphi(e_{m})} e_{m}$

I can't retrieve the rule allowing to replace the sum of inner products by the single inner product. How should that be understood?

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this answer in case someone could be as ignorant as I'm. As suggested by @dvdgrgrtt in a comment, I reviewed the properties of the inner product [presented in the book](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-031-41026-0.pdf#page=201):

- Additivity in the first slot: $\langle u+v, w \rangle = \langle u, w \rangle + \langle v, w \rangle$
- homogeneity in ﬁrst slot: $\langle \lambda u, v \rangle = \lambda \langle u, v \rangle$

None can be applied directly here. Instead we need the complements: Additivity in the second slot and antihomogeneity in the second slot. They are not explained in the book, but are [here](https://sharmaeklavya2.github.io/theoremdep/nodes/linear-algebra/inner-product-spaces/antilin-in-2nd.html).

- $\langle u, v+w \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle + \langle u, w \rangle$
- $\langle u, \lambda v \rangle = \overline \lambda \langle u, v \rangle$

---

$$
\begin {align}
\varphi(v)
&= \left\langle v, e_{1} \right\rangle \varphi(e_{1})
 + \dotsb
 + \left\langle v, e_{m} \right\rangle \varphi(e_{m})
\\
&= \color {mediumblue}{
\left\langle v, \overline {\varphi(e_{1})} e_{1} \right\rangle 
 + \dotsb
 + \left\langle v, \overline {\varphi(e_{m})} e_{m} \right\rangle
}\\
&= \left\langle 
   v,
   \overline {\varphi(e_{1})} e_{1} 
   + \dotsb
   + \overline {\varphi(e_{m})} e_{m}
   \right\rangle 
\end {align}
$$

Comment: Your book lets you discover some of the properties by yourself ;) Antihomogeneity in the second slot can be derived from homogeneity in the first slot and conjugate symmetry - give it a try!

Comment: @dvdgrgrtt: Yes, that's how it it proved in the linked page.

Comment: The statement above that additivity in the second slot and anti-homogeneity in the second slot are not explained in my book Linear Algebra Done Right is not correct. Specifically, see 6.6(d) for additivity in the second slot and 6.6(e) for anti-homogeneity in the second slot. Here all references are to the new fourth edition of the book, whose electronic version is freely available at https://linear.axler.net/.

Comment: @SheldonAxler: That's also what I understood from Xander's answer. I read it, but I also forgot. Thanks for confirming. Btw, good reading for self-learning.

Answer (score 2):

On page 183 of the [Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-031-41026-0.pdf#page=201) a definition of an inner product is given:

> **Definition:**  An *inner product* on [a vector space] $V$ is a function that takes each ordered pair $(u,v)$ of element of $V$ to a number $\langle u,v\rangle \in F$ and has the following properties:
>
> - **positivity:** $\langle v,v\rangle \ge 0$ for all $v\in V$;
> - **definiteness:** $\langle v,v\rangle = 0$ if and onlhy if $v = 0$;
> - **additivity in the first slot:**  $\langle u+v,w\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle + \langle v,w\rangle$ for all $u,v,w\in V$;
> - **homogeneity in the first slot:** $\langle \lambda u v\rangle = \lambda \langle u,v\rangle$ for all $\lambda \in F$ and all $u,v\in V$; and
> - **conjugage symmetry:** $\langle u,v \rangle = \overline{\langle u,v\rangle}$ for all $u,v\in V$.

There are two key ideas here:

- First, an inner product is linear in the second slot, as well: if $u,v,w \in V$, then

$$\begin{align} \langle u, v+w \rangle
&= \overline{\langle v+w, \rangle} && \text{(conjugate symmetry)} \\
&= \overline{\langle v,u\rangle + \langle w, u \rangle} &&\text{(additivity in the first slot)} \\
&= \overline{\langle v,u\rangle} + \overline{\langle w,u\rangle} \\
&= \langle u, v\rangle + \langle u, w\rangle.
\end{align}$$

- Second, an inner product is conjugate linear (or anti-homogeneous) in the second slot:  if $\lambda \in F$ and $u,v\in V$, then
  \begin{align}
  \lambda \langle u,v\rangle
  &= \lambda \overline{\langle v,u\rangle} && \text{(conjugate symmetry)} \\
  &= \overline{\overline{\lambda} \langle v,u \rangle} \\
  &= \overline{\langle \overline{\lambda}v,u\rangle} && \text{(homogeneity in the first slot)} \\
  &= \langle u, \overline{\lambda}v \rangle. && \text{(conjugage symmetry)}
  \end{align}

Note that both of these properties are discussed on [page 185](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-031-41026-0.pdf#page=203), and proofs are given.  These two properties can be applied to get the desired result:
$$
\begin {align}
\varphi(v)
&= \left\langle v, e_{1} \right\rangle \varphi(e_{1})
 + \dotsb
 + \left\langle v, e_{m} \right\rangle \varphi(e_{m})
\\
&= \left\langle v, \overline{\varphi(e_1)}e_1 \right\rangle
 + \dotsb
 + \left\langle v, \overline{\varphi(e_n)}e_n \right\rangle
 && \text{(anti-homogeneity)}
\\
&= \left\langle 
   v,
   \overline {\varphi(e_{1})} e_{1} 
   + \dotsb
   + \overline {\varphi(e_{m})} e_{m}
   \right\rangle. && \text{(linearity in the second term)}
\end {align}
$$